# find nearest cell with a specific value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have to developp a little program in vba (which I don't use very much).

I have a sheet with "parent" lines, and for each parent, I have a list of "child" lines :

```
line 1 parent
line 2 childa
line 3 childb
line 4
line 5 parent
line 6 childc
line 7 childd
line 8
line 9 parent
line 10 childe
```

I have to export these data in a new file, and be able to tell from each child at which parent he is connected.

To do that I want to develop a macro with the following principe :

For a child, I keep his line number in memory, then I do a findnext on parent until I exceed the line keep in memory. Basically when I am on a child, I want to find the cell of his closest parent starting from the top of the sheet.
Exemple : I call a function with the input parameter 2, I would like to get in return line 1.
input : line 7, return : line 5

As I am not very familiar with vba, I am struggling a lot, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Macro that uses the method you suggest.
When a child is selected and the macro is run it will find the closest parent above the child providing:

1) A1 is blank

2) There is a blank cell between each family

3) The families are in column A

```
Sub FindParent()
    Dim ChildRow As Integer
    Dim line As Integer
    Dim Pline As Variant
    Dim Parent As String

    ChildRow = ActiveCell.Row   'find the row of the child
    line = 1                                 'Start at row one

    Do Until line = ChildRow        'check each cell if it is blank, if so the next cell is a parent.
        If Range("A" & CStr(line)).Value = "" Then
            Pline = line + 1
        End If
        line = line + 1
    Loop

    Parent = Range("A" & Pline).Value
    MsgBox ("The parent of " & ActiveCell.Value & " is " & Parent & ".")

End Sub
```

This returns the result in a message box however this can easily be changed

Comment: Paste the code into a module. Adding a button to the spread sheet will make it easy to use